# Is there any Incoming SMS Broadcast Receiver like Receiver in iOS

Tags: ios, sms, nsnotificationcenter

I need to verify account using reading sms and then matching the verify code.
Android have such functionality [like](http://androidexample.com/Incomming_SMS_Broadcast_Receiver_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=62&aaid=87) :

where they can read sms and check a particular value.
Need to verify account using text messages without open the text message like in Whatsapp used in Android.

Is there any `NSNotification Center` etc in iOS to serve this task?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this on iOS, since your app does not have acces to the incoming text messages.
Also it is disallowed by the AppStore review guidelines due too privacy concerns.

Comment: any chance in IOS 8.1 or 8.2 beta ?

Comment: No, Apple will never allow it since they can no longer guarantee the users privacy.

Answer (score 0):

You can get OTP from your message.

```
otptextField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
```

Can please get the project from his link.

https://github.com/karthickkck315/Automatic-OTP